# Pass several data from controller to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Can't seem to find an answer, I'm a noob at .net. I'm trying to pass several data from controller to view.

Here's my controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ProjectWizNet.Models;

namespace ProjectWizNet.Controllers
{
    public class ClientController : Controller
    {
        private MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext();

    }

    // GET: Client/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            //return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            return View("_RecordNotFound");
        }

        Client client = db.Clients.Find(id);
        var projects = from p in db.Projects
            where p.ClientId == id
            select p;

        if (client == null)
        {
            //return HttpNotFound();
            return View("_RecordNotFound");
        }

        ViewBag.Title = "Edit";

        return View(client);
    }
}
```

so I have client that query the database to get a client record. I also have projects that query the database where the foreign key is projects.ClientId. where I get lost is

```
return View(client)
```

I'm coming from laravel php and how I would do this is use a data array. so something like

```
$data["clients"] = my query to get client;
$data["projects"] = my query to get project;

return view($data);
```

is it a similar approach in .net mvc? or is it a different way? do I create a model view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Controller should not pass domain model *(Client and Project)* to View directly. Instead, you need to convert them to View Models.

### Model

```
public class ClientViewModel
{
   // Properties
}

public class ProjectViewModel
{
   // Properties
}

public class EditViewModel
{
    public ClientViewModel Client { get; set; }
    public IList<ProjectViewModel> Projects { get; set; }
}
```

### Controller

If your project is large, you want to use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/).

```
var clientViewModel = db.Clients.Where(x => x.Id == id)
    .Select(x => new ClientViewModel
    {
        // Map Client domain model to Client view model
    })
    .FirstOrDefault();

var projectViewModels = from p in db.Projects
    where p.ClientId == id
    select new ProjectViewModel
    {
        // Map Project domain model to Project view model
    };

var editViewModel = new EditViewModel
    {
        Client = clientViewModel,
        Projects = projectViewModels
    };

return View(editViewModel);
```

### View

```
@model YourProjectNamespace.Models.EditViewModel

@foreach (var project in Model.Projects)
{
    // Print project
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use ViewData.  If you want to bring data to the view and display it you could use the following in the controller.

```
ViewData["projects"] = project.ToList();
```

In the view you could do something like this

```
<ul>
<% foreach(var item in (ViewData["projects"] as List<Project>)){%>
   <li>
       <%=item.ClientName%>
   </li>
<% } %>
</ul>
```

My preference is to use ViewModels because it is more organized but this is good for simple pages.  I can give you an example of that if you want.